# Git "Ancestry References"

Tags: git

I have difficulty to understand how is this thing works in git and who is parent and who is the grandparent. In addition,  what is the different between ^ and ~ in Git.

```
* 9ec05ca (HEAD -> master) Revert "Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades""
* db7e87a Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades"
*   796ddb0 Merge branch 'heading-update'
|\  
| * 4c9749e (heading-update) Set page heading to "Crusade"
* | 0c5975a Set page heading to "Quest"
|/  
*   1a56a81 Merge branch 'sidebar'
|\  
| * f69811c (sidebar) Update sidebar with favorite movie
| * e6c65a6 Add new sidebar content
* | e014d91 (footer) Add links to social media
* | 209752a Improve site heading for SEO
* | 3772ab1 Set background color for page
|/  
* 5bfe5e7 Add starting HTML structure
* 6fa5f34 Add .gitignore file
* a879849 Add header to blog
* 94de470 Initial commit
```

And how to answer this ?

You did so well on that last one, why not give this one a go! Using the same repository, which commit is referenced by HEAD~4^2?

Comment: It's the second parent of the fourth parent (favoring 1st parent) of HEAD. So HEAD is 9ec05ca, HEAD~1 is db7e87a, HEAD~2 is 796ddb0, HEAD~3 is 0c5975a, HEAD~4 is 1a56a81, and HEAD~4^2 is f69811c.

Comment: Not sure how you got to f69811c from '^2'

Answer (score 3):

> I have difficulty to understand how is this thing works in git and who is parent and who is the grandparent. In addition, what is the different between ^ and ~ in Git.

The first thing to remember is that `^` refers only to parents while `~` refers to ancestors.  `COMMIT^2` refers to the second parent of a commit, while `COMMIT~2` refers to the second ancestor.

### Parents

A simple commit in git has only a single parent, while a merge commit has at least two.  So in your example, commit `796ddb0` has two parents:

```
                         * 9ec05ca (HEAD -> master) Revert "Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades""
                         * db7e87a Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades"
                         *   796ddb0 Merge branch 'heading-update'
                         |\  
THIS IS PARENT #2 -->    | * 4c9749e (heading-update) Set page heading to "Crusade"
THIS IS PARENT #1 -->    * | 0c5975a Set page heading to "Quest"
```

`796ddb0^1` refers to `0c5975a`, because we count parents starting on
the left.  `796ddb0^2` refers to `4c9749e`.

### Ancestors

An ancestor is any commit on the path between your specified commit and the root of your repository, always following the first parent in the case that a commit has multiple parents.  So if we were to label the ancestors of `HEAD` in the first part of your example, we would end up with:

```
        * 9ec05ca (HEAD -> master) Revert "Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades""
HEAD~1   * db7e87a Set page heading to "Quests & Crusades"
HEAD~2   *   796ddb0 Merge branch 'heading-update'
         |\  
         | * 4c9749e (heading-update) Set page heading to "Crusade"
HEAD~3   * | 0c5975a Set page heading to "Quest"
         |/  
HEAD~4   *   1a56a81 Merge branch 'sidebar'
```

### Finally

We can break down `HEAD~4^2` into two operations:

- `HEAD~4` refers to commit `1a56a81`. That is a merge commit with
  two parents, so...
- `1a56a81^2` refers to `f69811c`

Comment: Wow, that really helped. This was a question at Udacity if anyone wanted to know where the question came from https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud123/lessons/f02167ad-3ba7-40e0-a157-e5320a5b0dc8/concepts/fed81eb7-49b4-4129-9f6b-8201e0796fd8